# Exeute custom method when the test execution is halted

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest, specflow

We are in the situation when the database used as our test environment db must be kept clean. It means that every test has a cleanup method which will be run after each execution at it deletes from the db every data which needed for the test.

We use Specflow and to achieve our goal to keep the db clean is reachable by using this tool if the test execution is not halted. But, during developing the test cases happens that the test execution is halted so the generated data in the db is not cleaned up.

The question came up what happens when I press the "Halt execution" in VS 2013? How the VS stops the execution? What method will be called? It is possible to customize it?

The specflow uses MSTest framework and there is no option to change it.

Comment: How do you currently clean up your DB? Do you use SpecFlow hooks (e.g. AfterScenario) to execute the DB clean up code?

Comment: @Fresh, yes, that's correct.

Comment: When you halt execution the application gets unloaded. (similar to `taskkill /im app.exe /f`) No further interaction is possible at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how practical this is going to be for you, but as I see it you have a couple of options:

- Run the cleanup code at the start and end of the test
- Create a new database for every test

The first is the simplest and will ensure that when you stop execution in VS it won't impact the next test run (of the same test) as any remaining data will be cleaned up when the test runs.

The second is more complicated to set up (and slower when it runs) but means that you can run your tests in parallel (so is good if you use tools like NCrunch), and they won't interfere with each other.

What I have done ion the past is make the DB layer switchable so you can run the tests against in memory data most of the time, and then switch to the DB once in a while to check that the actual reading and writing stuff isn't broken

This isn't too onerous if you use EF6 and can switch the `IDBSet<T>` for some other implementation backed by an in memory `IQueryable<>` implementation